# Tiger team versus red team?

Tags: penetration-test

What's the difference between a tiger team and a red team? Are there any other "color" teams out there (relevant to IT security)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have only heard of two types of teams:

- Blue team - The defenders of a network
- Red team - Attackers of a network
- Tiger team - Same as red team, however is a older term of the attacking/opposition side of an engagement
- White team - The team that establishes the rules of engagement and are usually the employees of the organization. The white team does not conduct any testing.

[CISSP study guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/111810594X) has the following explanation of the different teams:

> White team  A neutral team of employees acting as observers, referees, and judges between > a red team of mock attackers (offenders) and a blue team of actual defenders of their 
>   enterprise’s use of information systems. The white team establishes rules of engagement 
>   (ROE) and performance metrics for security tests. The white team is also responsible for 
>   deriving lessons-learned, conducting the post engagement assessment, and communicating 
>   results to management. Occasionally, the white team also performs incident response 
>   activities and addresses bot attacks on an emergency basis.

Comment: [CISSP Study Guide](http://www.amazon.com/CISSP-Study-Guide-Eric-Conrad/dp/1597495638) is better rated than the book linked to from above. Is your link wrong?

Comment: @nlovric, I just linked to the book I found the description of the different teams in :) Maybe the other book has the answer aswell and is in fact better, I dunno.

Comment: There's also the Purple Team, which is a mix between Red Team and Blue Team. Instead of the 2 working mostly separately trying to beat each other, they update and help each other more.

Answer (score 1):

from:  http://stormsecurity.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/phd_thesis_adrian_furtuna.pdf

> There are multiple definitions for *Red Teaming*, according to the specific domain of
>   activity (e.g. military, computers, corporate, etc).
>
> In the context of information security, the term **Red Teaming** is closely related to other
>   terms like penetration testing, ethical hacking, **tiger teaming**.
>
> Even though the terms penetration testing, ethical hacking and **tiger teaming** are not
>   precisely defined, they all refer to simulation of computer „hacking‟ activities for testing
>   the security of an information system.